# Parsing custom arguments in Powershell "-" delimitted

Tags: regex, parsing, powershell, arguments

I have a string

-car:"Nissan" -Model:"Dina" -Color:"Light-blue" -wheels:"4"

How can I extract the arguments? Initial thoughts was to use the '-' as the delimiter, however that's not going to work.

Comment: How is it related to PowerShell?

Answer (score 1):

Use of a regular expression is probably the easiest solution of the task. This can be done in PowerShell:

```
$text = @'
-car:"Nissan" -Model:"Dina" -Color:"Light-blue" -wheels:"4" -windowSize.Front:"24"
'@

# assume parameter values do not contain ", otherwise this pattern should be changed
$pattern = '-([\.\w]+):"([^"]+)"'

foreach($match in [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Matches($text, $pattern)) {
 $param = $match.Groups[1].Value
 $value = $match.Groups[2].Value
 "$param is $value"
}
```

Output:

```
car is Nissan
Model is Dina
Color is Light-blue
wheels is 4
windowSize.Front is 24
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. There's an additional requirement though.. If the arguments look like the following: -car:"Nissan" -Model:"Dina" -Color:"Light-blue" -wheels:"4" -windowSize.Front:"24" -windowSize.Back:"26"

How can the regex be changed to cater for these

Comment: @Henno, I have updated the answer so that it includes the new case.